# Is it possible to make an installer for a php Application?

Tags: php, windows, cakephp-2.0

Does it possible to make a installer file that can install my PHP application into my localhost.

Comment: Yes it is possible. It had been done many times. For example take: XAMPP. If you would like to get more details, please include the server you would like to use.

Comment: Why did this receive an upvote? Yes it's possible...

Comment: Attila thanks.. but how could i make a installer.bat file that can copy the whole application including  XAMPP . and also set necessary Environment Variable in my windows PATH  ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can focus on "automatic deployment" using tools like these one:

- [Capistrano](http://www.davegardner.me.uk/blog/2012/02/13/php-deployment-with-capistrano/)
- [Phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/)